# I cannot install React-Native on "npm install -g react-native-cli" Macbook

Tags: node.js, macos, react-native, npm, npm-install

When I try to do `npm install -g react-native-cli` I get this error message:

```
Gire-Mac-MacBook-Pro:/ Gire-mac$ npm install -g react-native-cli
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.9.1/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Also when I try to learn `npm` version I got same message.
My `node.js` version is 8.9.1. I used `Homebrew` version 1.3.8 for installation. I am new at this React Native projects and I still cannot start a project.

Comment: check this  : http://npmjs.com/package/create-react-native-app

Comment: Do you get the same error if you `npm install -g` anything else?

Comment: npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Gire-mac/.npm/_logs/2017-11-25T11_45_14_702Z-debug.log         I got this error message when "I tried npm install -g"

Comment: What he meant was installing another global module via `npm install -g somethingelse` and seeing if your installation is botched or if the issue was strictly related to react-native-cli. In any case, If you installed node/npm via Homebrew you might wanna [take a look at this](https://gist.github.com/rcugut/c7abd2a425bb65da3c61d8341cd4b02d)

Comment: I could success react-native but I can not initialize a project right now when I try "react native init myProject" it returns me react-native: command not found. Btw my problem, I am not sure but I think because of my other java project. I also use in this project node.js. I deleted it and it fixed.